# How to use enable_if for restricting a whole class

Tags: c++, c++11

I know I can use a static_assert and make sure that type T is numeric but I want to use std::enable_if. How can I force Vector3D class below to be numeric only using std::enable_if or std::conditional without inheriting?

```
template<typename T>
class Vector3D
{
    private:
        T X, Y, Z;
};
```

I tried:

```
template<typename T>
class Vector3D<typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type>
{
    private:
        T X, Y, Z;
};
```

Comment: What's wrong with `static_assert`?

Comment: `enable_if` wouldn't do anything here that `static_assert` doesn't already do.  In fact, it would do less.

Comment: indeed for a class static_assert looks like the good tool, while enable_if for functions adjusting the overload set.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you really want to use `enable_if`, you can write your class template this way:

```
template<typename T, typename = typename     
    std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type>
class Vector3D
{
    private:
        T X, Y, Z;
};
```

However, as others have noticed, you may be better off with using `static_assert`.

Comment: :o! Why would static_assert be better though?

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: For instance, it would not allow the client to specify a second template argument, thus bypassing the `enable_if`

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: You tell us why you think it's worse. :)

Comment: No I wasn't sure if it was worst. I thought std::enable_if would not be bypassed and just make it not compile. I didn't want to supply a message to static_assert. I prefer the compiler to just throw one at compile time. That's why I didn't want to use static_asssert.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: Programmer-specified errors are probably much nicer than SFINAE errors...hell, before `static_assert` existed one of the top features of a custom static assert macro was the ability to specify messages!

Comment: I guess so but I at least wanted the option for the compiler to give one. I used the static_assert but I commented Andy's solution. :)

Comment: @AndyProwl: Could you redirect me to some tutorial that explains what's the meaning of `typename **=** typename ....` (This is the first time I see `typename =`), or simply explain this? Thanks!

Comment: @segfolt: template parameters can have default arguments (that's what the `=` introduces), and they do not need to have a name (just like function parameters). The above template has a second unnamed parameter whose default value is given by `typename std::enable_if<...>::type`